# Prove sum of arithmetic series is $\frac{1}{4}n(x + y)$ given sum of first two and last two members.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am working through a maths text book as a hobby. I have come across this problem:

Given that the sum of the first and second terms of an arithmetic progression is x and the sum of the $(n -1)$th  and nth terms is y, prove that the sum of the first n terms is $\frac{1}{4}n(x + y)$

If $u_{n}$ refers to the nth term of the series, I know $u_{1} +  u_{n} = u_{2} + u_{n - 1}$ and also that $S_{n} = \frac{1}{2}n\{2a + (n -1)d\}$, where a refers to the first member and d is the common difference. But I cannot put this knowledge together to work out the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the spirit of [Gauss](https://nrich.maths.org/2478):

$$\begin{array}{rc}
S_n &=& u_1 &+& u_2 &+& u_3 &+& \cdots &+& u_{n-2} &+& u_{n-1} &+& u_n \\
S_n &=& u_n &+& u_{n-1} &+& u_{n-2} &+& \cdots &+& u_3 &+& u_2 &+& u_1 \\
2S_n &=& C &+& C &+& C &+& \cdots &+& C &+& C &+& C
\end{array}$$
where:
$$2C = u_1+u_n+u_2+u_{n-1} = x+y$$
so:
$$C = \dfrac{x+y}2$$
so:
$$2S_n = nC = \dfrac12 n(x+y)$$
so:
$$S_n = \frac14n(x+y)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$S_n=\dfrac n2(a+a_n)$$
$$S_n=\dfrac n2(a_2+a_{n-1})$$
Add these two equations together and use definition of $x$ and $y$.